# How to send model View from Action result?

Tags: model, action

I want to send the model in View to a different ActionResult as a model.
I tried,
@ Html.Action (“xxx”, ”xxx", model) but it doesn't send. How can i do ?

Comment: Unable to understand the error. Please give more details.

Comment: on PageView, i use this code --> @Html.action("GetCustomer", "Customer",model) and this model came null